# What expression would I use to stay in this switch statement?

Tags: java

I have the pieces that work which is the final total of the burgers, however I can't seem to keep the loop going so that if I select 1 it, grabs the burger and ask me to select again, adding more to the total. When I'm done it exits out and shows the final total and if I press 2. And other number it states in the loop and ask me again.

I don't know what to put into the switch statement to keep it going. Based on what I have I tried I tend to get the statement: "Cannot switch on a value of type boolean. Only convertible int values, strings or enum variables are permitted"

Based on what I have so far, I'm stuck.

```
boolean valid = true;

do {
            System.out.println("Select an Option: ");
            int userInput = scnr.nextInt();

    switch (userInput <=2) {

        case 1:
                burgerOrder++;
                subTotalBurgers = burgerPrice * burgerOrder;
                finalSubTotal = burgerPrice * tax;
                finalBurgerTotal = burgerPrice + tax;
            break;
        case 2:
                System.out.println("2. Exit");
            valid = true; 
        default: 
            System.out.println("Sorry");
                continue;
        }
}while(!valid); 

        System.out.println("BurgerOrder is " + finalBurgerTotal);
```

Answer (score 3):

`switch (userInput)`. The `<= 2` is making it a `boolean` expression and is not necessary since you have a `default` case. Your loop requires that `valid` have an initial value of `false` (since that is your loop condition). And, you missed a `break` in `case 2`.

```
boolean valid = false;
do {
    switch (userInput) {
    case 1:
        burgerOrder++;
        subTotalBurgers = burgerPrice * burgerOrder;
        finalSubTotal = burgerPrice * tax;
        finalBurgerTotal = burgerPrice + tax;
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println("2. Exit");
        valid = true; 
        break;
    default: 
        System.out.println("Sorry");
        continue;
    }
} while (!valid);
```

Comment: I actually tried just userInput but it doesn't keep repeating until I tell it it stop. I would like it to ask me again so I can add another burger. With just userInput it jumps straight out and prints the result.

Comment: @JackieTowns *I actually tried just userInput but it doesn't keep repeating until I tell it it stop.* Change `boolean valid = true;` to `boolean valid = false;`

Comment: Thank you! That helped! But do you know why it still captures the default statement in the output and why when I repeat the action of selecting 1 the total is still the same as for 1 burger?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Missing `break` from case 2 ?

Comment: Thanks so much!! Actually I had an incorrect equation for what I wanted to do. But the help you provided was much appreciated as my switch statement is working now!!

Answer (score -1):

Your `continue` statement tells the program to break out of the loop. Just delete that.

For what it's worth, your `case 2` also falls through to "default"; you might have intended a `break` statement after `case 2`.

And whatever you use as an expression for the `switch` statement is evaluated to see what case to go to -- `userInput <= 2` seems unlikely for values of 1 and 2.

Comment: I thought that `continue` means continue at the top of the loop?